# Centreon, OID no obtengo datos

Tags: linux, centos

Buenas, estoy intentando monitorizar a traves de OID en Centreon pues lo necesito para una impresora.

Consigo los OID de la impresora realizando el siguiente comando:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -On -c public <IP>
```

Una vez los obtengo voy a Centreon y escribo el siguiente comando en la página web:

```
$USER1$/check_snmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c public -o  .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.1
```

El caso es que "funciona" por que devuelve esto:

```
Command Line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H 172.27.1.251 -c  public -o .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.1
Output  SNMP OK - "PROCESSING" |
Status  OK
```

Pero si quiero que me indique un W o C me da el siguiente error:

```
$USER1$/check_snmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c public -o  .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.1 -w 5 -c 10

Command Line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H 172.27.1.251 -c   public -o .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.1 -w 5 -c 10
Output  No valid data returned ("PROCESSING")
Status  UNKNOWN
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es que me muestre las caracteristicas normales: capacidad del Toner, etc ,etc; con un plugin que encontre en GitHub funciona pero tengo otra impresora que queremos hacerlo funcionar por OID y siempre conseguimos los mismos mensajes.

Snmp walk completo de la impresora que quiero monitorizar:

```html
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: KYOCERA MITA Printing System
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.41
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.1.1 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.2.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.6.1 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.7.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.8.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.9.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.10.1 = INTEGER: 6
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.11.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.12.1 = INTEGER: 80
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.13.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.14.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.15.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.16.1 = STRING: "FS-C8025MFP"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1 = STRING: "Q731604568"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.18.1 = Counter32: 57
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.19.1 = Counter32: 299
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.2.1.1 = STRING: "Front Cover"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.2.1.2 = STRING: "Right Cover 1"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.2.1.3 = STRING: "Right Cover 2"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.2.1.4 = STRING: "Document Processor Cover"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.3.1.3 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.6.1.1.3.1.4 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.1 = STRING: "en"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.2 = STRING: "fr"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.3 = STRING: "de"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.4 = STRING: "it"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.5 = STRING: "nl"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.6 = STRING: "es"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.7 = STRING: "ru"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2.1.8 = STRING: "pt"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.1 = STRING: "US"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.2 = STRING: "FR"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.3 = STRING: "DE"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.4 = STRING: "IT"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.5 = STRING: "NL"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.6 = STRING: "ES"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.7 = STRING: "RU"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.3.1.8 = STRING: "BR"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.1 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.3 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.4 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.5 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.6 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.7 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.4.1.8 = INTEGER: 106
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.2.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.3.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.3.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.4.1.1 = INTEGER: 170078
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 116900
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.4.1.3 = INTEGER: 116900
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.4.1.4 = INTEGER: 165333
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.5.1.1 = INTEGER: 116929
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.5.1.2 = INTEGER: 82667
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.5.1.3 = INTEGER: 82667
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.5.1.4 = INTEGER: 117000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.6.1.1 = INTEGER: 170078
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.6.1.2 = INTEGER: 116900
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.6.1.3 = INTEGER: 116900
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.6.1.4 = INTEGER: 165333
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.7.1.1 = INTEGER: 116929
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.7.1.2 = INTEGER: 82667
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.7.1.3 = INTEGER: 82667
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.7.1.4 = INTEGER: 117000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.8.1.1 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.8.1.2 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.8.1.3 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.8.1.4 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 100
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.9.1.2 = INTEGER: 500
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.9.1.3 = INTEGER: 500
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.9.1.4 = INTEGER: 500
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.10.1.1 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.10.1.2 = INTEGER: 150
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.10.1.3 = INTEGER: 150
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.10.1.4 = INTEGER: 150
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.11.1.1 = INTEGER: 19
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.11.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.11.1.3 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.11.1.4 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.12.1.1 = STRING: "Normal"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.12.1.2 = STRING: "Normal"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.12.1.3 = STRING: "Normal"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.12.1.4 = STRING: "Normal"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.15.1.1 = STRING: "MP Tray"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.15.1.2 = STRING: "Cassette 1"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.15.1.3 = STRING: "PF-471"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.15.1.4 = STRING: "PF-471"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.18.1.1 = STRING: "MP Tray"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.18.1.2 = STRING: "Cassette 1"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.18.1.3 = STRING: "Cassette 2"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.18.1.4 = STRING: "Cassette 3"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.19.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.19.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.19.1.3 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.19.1.4 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.4.1.1 = INTEGER: 250
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 100
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.5.1.1 = INTEGER: -2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.5.1.2 = INTEGER: -2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.6.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.6.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.9.1.1 = STRING: "Inner Tray"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.9.1.2 = STRING: "Job Separator"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.12.1.1 = STRING: "Inner Tray"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.12.1.2 = STRING: "Job Separator Tray[Face-down]"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.13.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.13.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.14.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.14.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.15.1.1 = INTEGER: 177000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.15.1.2 = INTEGER: 177000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.16.1.1 = INTEGER: 117000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.16.1.2 = INTEGER: 117000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.17.1.1 = INTEGER: 58000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.17.1.2 = INTEGER: 58000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.18.1.1 = INTEGER: 31496
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.18.1.2 = INTEGER: 31496
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.19.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.19.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.20.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.20.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.21.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.21.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.22.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.22.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.23.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.23.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.24.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.9.2.1.24.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1 = Counter32: 137103
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.5.1.1 = Counter32: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.6.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.7.1.1 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.8.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 600
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.10.1.1 = INTEGER: 600
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.11.1.1 = INTEGER: 1968
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.12.1.1 = INTEGER: 1968
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.13.1.1 = INTEGER: 1968
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.14.1.1 = INTEGER: 1968
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.15.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.4 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.5 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.4 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.5 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.4.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.4.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.4.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.4.1.5 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.5 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.1 = STRING: "TK-895C"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.2 = STRING: "TK-895M"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.3 = STRING: "TK-895Y"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.4 = STRING: "TK-895K"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.5 = STRING: "Waste Toner Box"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.1 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.2 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.3 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.4 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.5 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.1 = INTEGER: 6000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.2 = INTEGER: 6000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.3 = INTEGER: 6000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.4 = INTEGER: 12000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.5 = INTEGER: -2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 5280
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.2 = INTEGER: 2880
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.3 = INTEGER: 1680
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.4 = INTEGER: 9960
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.5 = INTEGER: -3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.2.1.4 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.3.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.3.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.4.1.1 = STRING: "cyan"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.4.1.2 = STRING: "magenta"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.4.1.3 = STRING: "yellow"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.4.1.4 = STRING: "black"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.5.1.1 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.5.1.2 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.5.1.3 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.5.1.4 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.3.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.4.1.1 = INTEGER: 1500
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 1500
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.4.1.3 = INTEGER: 1500
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.5.1.1 = INTEGER: 177000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.5.1.2 = INTEGER: 177000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.5.1.3 = INTEGER: 177000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.6.1.1 = INTEGER: 117000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.6.1.2 = INTEGER: 117000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.6.1.3 = INTEGER: 117000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.7.1.1 = INTEGER: 58000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.7.1.2 = INTEGER: 83000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.7.1.3 = INTEGER: 83000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.8.1.1 = INTEGER: 31496
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.8.1.2 = INTEGER: 58000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.8.1.3 = INTEGER: 58000
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.9.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.9.1.3 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.10.1.1 = STRING: "Simplex"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.10.1.2 = STRING: "Long edge binding"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.10.1.3 = STRING: "Short edge binding"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.11.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.11.1.2 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.13.4.1.11.1.3 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 34
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 11
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.4 = INTEGER: 44
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.5 = INTEGER: 13
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.6 = INTEGER: 27
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.7 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.8 = INTEGER: 10
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.9 = INTEGER: 9
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.10 = INTEGER: 41
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.2.1.11 = INTEGER: 43
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.1 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.3 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.4 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.5 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.6 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.7 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.8 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.9 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.10 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.4.1.11 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.2 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.3 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.4 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.5 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.6 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.7 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.8 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.9 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.10 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.5.1.11 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.5 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.6 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.7 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.8 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.9 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.10 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.6.1.11 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.1 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.2 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.3 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.4 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.5 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.6 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.7 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.8 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.9 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.10 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.14.1.1.8.1.11 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 47
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 6
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.2.1.4 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.2.1.5 = INTEGER: 50
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.2.1.6 = INTEGER: 37
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.3.1.1 = STRING: "5c"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.3.1.2 = STRING: "3.0"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.3.1.3 = STRING: "3"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.3.1.4 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.3.1.5 = STRING: "2c"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.3.1.6 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.4.1.1 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.4.1.2 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.4.1.3 = STRING: "3011.103"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.4.1.4 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.4.1.5 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.4.1.6 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.5.1.1 = STRING: "PCL"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.5.1.2 = STRING: "PCLXL"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.5.1.3 = STRING: "KPDL"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.5.1.4 = STRING: "PJL"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.5.1.5 = STRING: "PRESCRIBE"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.5.1.6 = STRING: "AUTO"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.6.1.1 = STRING: "2011.04.11"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.6.1.2 = STRING: "2011.04.11"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.6.1.3 = STRING: "2011.04.11"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.6.1.4 = STRING: "2011.04.11"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.6.1.5 = STRING: "2011.04.11"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.6.1.6 = STRING: "2011.04.11"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.7.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.7.1.2 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.7.1.3 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.7.1.4 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.7.1.5 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.7.1.6 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.8.1.1 = INTEGER: 7200
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.8.1.2 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.8.1.3 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.8.1.4 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.8.1.5 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.8.1.6 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 7200
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.9.1.2 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.9.1.3 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.9.1.4 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.9.1.5 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.9.1.6 = INTEGER: -1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.10.1.1 = INTEGER: 2011
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.10.1.2 = INTEGER: 2004
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.10.1.3 = INTEGER: 2005
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.10.1.4 = INTEGER: 2004
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.10.1.5 = INTEGER: 2011
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.10.1.6 = INTEGER: 2004
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.11.1.1 = INTEGER: 2004
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.11.1.2 = INTEGER: 2004
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.11.1.3 = INTEGER: 2005
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.11.1.4 = INTEGER: 2004
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.11.1.5 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.11.1.6 = INTEGER: 2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.12.1.1 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.12.1.2 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.12.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.12.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.12.1.5 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.15.1.1.12.1.6 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.16.5.1.2.1.1 = STRING: "Preparada"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.2.1.4 = INTEGER: 100
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.3.1.3 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.3.1.4 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.4.1.1 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.4.1.3 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.4.1.4 = INTEGER: 3
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.1 = STRING: "PROCESSING"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.2 = STRING: "MEMORY"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.3 = STRING: "ATTENTION"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.4 = STRING: "BackLight"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 6
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.4.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.5.1.2 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.6.1.2 = INTEGER: 0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.7.1.2 = INTEGER: 503
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.2 = ""
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.9.1.2 = Timeticks: (1527) 0:00:15.27
.1.3.6.1.2.1.55.1.1.0 = INTEGER: notForwarding(2)
.1.3.6.1.2.1.55.1.2.0 = INTEGER: 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fallo de sintaxis

El parámetro `-c` donde pasas la community debería ir en mayúsculas `-C`

```
$USER1$/check_snmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C public -o  .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.1 -w 5 -c 10
```

Ya que `-c` es el parámetro para indicarle al `check_snmp` que valor para tí es el crítico, como bien utilizas después en la misma línea.

### Porque da error unknown en tu caso

El OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5 es para sacar información de la consola (pantalla de la impresora), de ahí que te saque lo de PROCESSING.

En cuanto al problema que te da cuando añades los parámetros de -c y -w es porque el valor que hay en el OID que estás indicando es formato texto, y él está esperando un numérico.

Dependiendo del modelo de impresora la información que buscas estará en uno u otro OID. Haz un `snmpwalk -v2c -On -c public <ip_impresora>` y revisa que es cada cosa en la [Printer-MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3805)

Piensa que además del Printer-MIB hay fabricantes que almacenan dicha información en el OID privado de cada uno de ellos. Tendrás que buscar la MIB de cada fabricante.

Lo normal para la tinta es que tengas en el 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.1 el valor máximo de tóner y en 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1 el valor actual. Con una pequeña regla de 3 puedes sacar el porcentaje. Si tu impresora es a color habrán 4 oids para cada uno de los máximos y 4 oids para los valores actuales.

### OIDs por defecto y situación de información de tóners

Los números de páginas impresas en BN suelen estar en 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1, las de color depende de cada fabricante.

Los tambores, fusibles y otro tipo de consumibles muchos fabricantes los ponen como si fuera otro *marker* (tinta).

### OIDs a utilizar en el caso de la impresora que indicas

En el caso de tu impresora estos son los OIDs que deberías utilizar:

Valor **máximo** del tóner **cyan**: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.1
Valor **actual** del tóner cyan: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1

Valor **máximo** del tóner **magenta**: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.2
Valor **actual** del tóner magenta: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.2

Valor **máximo** del tóner **amarillo**: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.3
Valor **actual** del tóner amarillo: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.3

Valor **máximo** del tóner **negro**: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.4
Valor **actual** del tóner negro: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.4

Valor **máximo** del **tóner residual**: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.5
Valor **actual** del tóner residual: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.5

Número total de **páginas impresas**: .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1  (salen ahora unas 137103)

Para el número de copias en color no veo nada. ¿Has puesto todo el snmp walk? Seguramente igual no te cabía todo en el jsfiddle. Pega lo que vaya detrás del .1.3.6.1.2.1.43 en https://pastebin.com/

En el tóner residual si te fijas el valor máximo es -2, pero en el actual tiene -3. Según la MIB de dicho OID -3 significa que aún queda de dicho consumible, y -2 significa desconocido. En tu caso -3 es correcto, y otra cosa significará que o bien está lleno, o que no se detecta la botella de tóner residual.

### Script para monitorizar el % de tinta restante

Para monitorizar correctamente los toners que te he puesto antes te hará falta un script que haga la regla de tres, que será el que tendrás que llamar desde el centreon pasándole como parámetros el OID con el valor máximo y el OID con el valor actual.

Te pongo un script que me hice yo hace tiempo. Guardarlo en el mismo directorio donde tienes los otros scripts de check de centreon y llamalo por ejemplo `get_tinta_x100.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
#declare -i actual
#declare -i total
#declare -i ret

if [ "X$3" = "X" ]; then
        echo "get_tinta_x100: Could not parse arguments"
        echo "Usage:"
        echo "      get_tinta_x100 <host> <oid_with_current_value_of_tint> <oid_with_max_value_of_tint>"
        exit
fi

actual=`/usr/bin/snmpget -v 1 -Cf -O U -c public $1 $2 | awk '{print $4}' 2>/dev/null`
total=`/usr/bin/snmpget -v 1 -Cf -O U -c public $1 $3 | awk '{print $4}' 2>/dev/null`

if [ "$total" = "0" ]; then
        echo -1
else
        ret=$(echo "scale=9;tmp=($actual*100)/$total; tmp+=0.5; scale=0; tmp/=1; tmp" | bc 2>/dev/null)
        echo "k:$ret"
fi
```

Comment: Eso, lo sabía pero ya no sabía como ponerlo, pero mira, si lo pogno con la `C` mayúscula de la comunidad me da este error: `Command Line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H 172.27.1.251 -C public -o .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.17.6.1.5.1.1 -w 5 -c 10
Output No valid data returned ("PROCESSING")
Status UNKNOWN`

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta explicándote el problema del OID y te he puesto los OIDs más típicos que se suelen utilizar para las impresoras.

Comment: No sabía como hacerte llegar todas esta slíneas asi que pense en un Jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/cqLg2mh7/ En el `HTML` van los `OID` de mi impresora, en `JavaScript` el resultado de los check y el `CSS` los archivos de los que dispongo

Comment: Que datos quieres mostrar en el Centreon? Núm páginas, toner restante ???

Comment: Si, esas dos cosas serían lo normal diria yo la carga de los toner y las paginas que resten

Comment: Te he añadido más cosas en la respuesta. ¿Páginas que resten? En la parte de la MIB que has puesto no está esa información. Seguramente en la MIB privada puede que lo publique la impresora.

Comment: Vale aquí lo tienes, e vuelto a realizar los chekeos de los OID, lo que no se es comos abes el valor para - 2 y -3, y acabo de ver lo de las páginas imprimidas ahora mismo y no sabia que ese numero era el de las páginas xD! https://pastebin.com/1WbzJJif

Comment: Lo del -2 y -3 lo pone en la MIB. Digamos que es el documento del estándar que define todo este tema del snmp de impresoras. `The Printer MIB has also defined the following special values for use
   with objects of the syntax "Integer32" to define conditions that are
   outside of the normal numeric range:  other(-1), unknown(-2), and
   partial(-3).  The 'partial' value means that there is some supply
   remaining (but the amount is indeterminate) or there is some capacity
   remaining (but the amount is indeterminate).`

Comment: El snmpwalk acaba en el oid .1.3.6.1.2.1.55.1.2.0? No hay más? Si hay más modifica el pastebin y pega desde ese OID hasta el final. También vendría bien saber el número de copias en color justo en el momento de hacer el snmpwalk y así buscando el número de copias puedes sacar el OID donde almacena esa información. Puedes hacer por ejemplo un `snmpwalk -v2c -On -c public 172.27.1.251 | grep 137103` donde el 137103 sería el número de copias a color.

Comment: Exacto acaba en esa OID no tiene más, deberia de tener más? De donde puedo conseguir la información que citas sobre el MIB? Y una cosa, entonces trabajar con los OID que conlleva, por que si descargo un script de impreosra de exchange me dice exactos los % de toner, los OID solo dicen -1 -2 y -3

Comment: No sé. En la web de la impresora te pone las copias que lleva a color? Si es así debería de publicar dicho valor vía snmp también. El único valor que no da valor real es la botella de tóner residual. Para los toners si que se puede sacar el % con el script que te he puesto pasándole los oids necesarios. En snmp se puede trabajar con oids o con nombres, pero a efectos finales es lo mismo. La printer mib es un documento técnico público común para todas las impresoras de red https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3805

Comment: Un par de preguntillas faciles xD!.  Si yo pongo ./check_snmp -H 172.27.1.251 -C public -o  .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1.1.4.1.4 //Como traduzco yo esto -->//SNMP OK - "black" | //Luego en el del Toner el OID que me distes no lo veo en mi lista. Y por último en la página que me pasastes no veo donde se encuentran los OID aqui? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3805

Comment: Lo de snmp OK - "black" es porque estás listando la descripción del tóner. SNMP OK significa que ha accedido correctamente a lo que le has dicho, y lo que va entre comillas es el valor de lo que le has dicho. El RFC es el documento técnico, cada elemento dice quien es su padre y que número de hijo es él. Por ejemplo en `prtMarkerEntry` abajo te pone `::= { prtMarkerTable 1 }`, es decir tiene el OID de su padre (llamado prtMarkerTable) más un 1. En esta web puedes ver los oids más comodamente http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/Printer-MIB.html

Comment: Una cosilla y este error a que se debe? `SNMP TABLE ERROR : No response from remote host` ping si me funciona perfectamente pero cualquier otro comando me da este error

Comment: Dicha máquina en cuestión tiene habilitado el servicio snmp ? Puedes probar si el puerto está abierto con `nmap`: `nmap ip_de_la_maquina -p 161 -sU`